# My black cat's nose looks like it has a scab or weird booger

Tags: health, ears-nose-throat

My black cat's nose is usually full black but today it looks brighter and humid.
It has a weird spot that looks like a scar, scab or booger. I can't exactly tell.

Should I take her to the vet? How urgent?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have to rush to the emergency vet, but you certainly need to keep an eye on your cats behavior.

Has anything changed recently? Like the brand or type of food, the water or food bowl or the source of the water your cat drinks? Has your cat been outside and possibly ingested something she shouldn't have? Have you recently used a different cleaning product for your dishes or floors or surfaces where she walks? Has any container with some liquid (either drinks or other, non-food liquids) stood around unattended?

If the answer to any of these questions is "yes", make sure to remove the new object or switch back to old food and observe if the skin returns to normal.

In the meantime, watch your cat closely for any dificulty brathing or swallowing, like breathing sounds, coughing or wheezing, avoidance of food or water and excess drooling. The skin from nose to chin seems swollen, so the skin and tissue *inside* her mouth could be swollen, too. If you notice any signs, call your vet and make an appointment ASAP.

If you notice more severe signs, treat it as a medical emergency. You can see a list of typical poison symptoms at the [pet poison helpline](https://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/pet-owners/basics/signs-of-poisoning-in-dogs-and-cats/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looks like it was just a scratch on her nose. The vet saw her a week later for another unrelated appointment.